# Pivot part of a DB table to display in a GridView Using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, linq-to-entities

I'm building an ASP.NET Web Forms Application and there's a form where the user inputs some intervals.
he can input as many intervals as he wants, and it's stored in the DB in a table like this:

```
Employee Rank --- SalesMin --- SalesMax --- Pay
Admin ------------- 90 --------- 100 ------ 100 -- BUTTON
Admin ------------- 101 -------- 110 ------ 200 -- BUTTON
Admin ------------- 111 -------- 120 ------ 300 -- BUTTON
Manager ----------- 90 --------- 100 ------ 200 -- BUTTON
Manager ----------- 101 -------- 110 ------ 300 -- BUTTON
Manager ----------- 111 -------- 120 ------ 400 -- BUTTON
SalesPerson ------- 90 --------- 100 ------ 50 --- BUTTON
SalesPerson ------- 101 -------- 110 ------ 100 -- BUTTON
SalesPerson ------- 111 -------- 120 ------ 200 -- BUTTON
```

So depending on the number of sales a certain product had, each of the employee ranks are given the pay they're due.
The user can input as many intervals as he wants and each new interval is stored in a new row. In this example there are 3 different intervals, but it could be 4, 2, 5, as many as the user wants.
The number of intervals ir equal to all of the ranks, always.
this is the way it's stored in the database.

But! after inputing the intervals and everything else, the user needs to change the ammount payed, and that's what the button does(initially the values of pay are null).

What I need to do is: 
keeping this table like this in the DB, I need to display it in a GridView like this:

```
Employee Rank --- Interval1 --- Interval2 --- Interval3
Admin ------------- 100 --------- 200 ---------- 300 ----- button
Manager ----------- 200 --------- 300 ---------- 400 ----- button
Admin ------------- 50 ---------- 100 ---------- 200 ----- button
```

I need to take the number of rows corresponding to the intervals and turn them into columns and then edit the pay values with the button.
Then, I need to revert it back and save the alterations back into the DB table (the first one).

I can't seem to find a way to do that.
Is there a way?
Thanks.

PS: not sure if that's relevant but that first table is stored with mostly FK from other tables, I then use LINQ to Entities to put that together and I have a Class that's used to store the objects that that list contaigns.

Comment: Not sure if i was clear enough, I cant hardcode the gridview because the number of columns can vary deppending on the number of intervals the user had inputed before, it can have from 1 to as-many-as-the-dude-wants interval columns.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a nice little job for a `PIVOT`:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT [Employee Rank], [Pay], 'Interval' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Employee Rank] ORDER BY [Pay] ASC) AS VARCHAR) AS [Interval]
FROM Table1)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
PIVOT(MAX([Pay]) FOR [Interval] IN ([Interval1],[Interval2],[Interval3])) PIV
```

EDIT: There's loads of examples online showing you how to make this dynamic.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, is there a way to use Pivot in a LINQ query?

Comment: I failed to realise this is a LINQ solution. I'd recommend adding the `linq` tag to your question to maximise the chance of getting the answer you're looking for. It's not something I've touched base with yet unfortunately.